# extracting specific members of heatmap in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap

I generated a heatmap based on a 4500 row x 400 col matrix m:

```
hm<-heatmap(m, na.rm=TRUE, col=bluered(256))
```

So how do I see members of specific clusters? I read a bit and know that I have to use 'cutree()' but I am still not sure how to properly implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hm<-heatmap.2(m, na.rm=TRUE)
clstrs <- cutree(as.hclust(hm$rowDendrogram), 1:dim(m)[1])
```

And depending on how many clusters you want, you select the right column.  Thus if you want 7 clusters:

```
clstrs[, 7]
```

Will tell you in which cluster each element belongs.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. Does this only work in heatmap.2() or can I apply it to heatmap() as well?

Comment: I think it only works on heatmap.2;  if you don't want to install any new packages maybe you can try
    hcls <- hclust(dist(m));
    cutree(hcls, k = 6:7)